# Extracting lat/long from screen when using British National Grid projection in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, coordinate-system, united-kingdom

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0, is it possible to click anywhere on the map (projected to British National Grid), but return the coordinates in WGS84 lat long?

Comment: Please expand "Alternatively, when will Streetview work with OS Eastings and Northings?" on http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/streetview/ is in Eastings and Northings

Comment: By streetview are you referring to Google Maps streetview, or something else?

Comment: I should have specified Google Streetview, and not the OS product. Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with arcobjects you could [implement ITool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/0001000000m6000000.htm).  If using 10.0, you might find it easier to [create a tool add-in](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Building_add_ins_for_ArcGIS_Desktop/0001000000w2000000/).

In ITool.OnMouseDown take the x and y and convert it to an IPoint using [IDisplayTransformation.ToMapPoint](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ToMapPoint_Method/001w000000tm000000/).

I'm not that familiar the the British National Grid, but it appears that a [datum transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_National_Grid#Datum_shift_between_OSGB_36_and_WGS_84) is required when projecting to WGS84.

So, use [ISpatialReferenceFactory.CreateGeoTransformation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/CreateGeoTransformation_Method/002m000003p1000000/) to create the appropriate datum transformation, and [ISpatialReferenceFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem_Method/002m000003p0000000/) to create the target (WGS84) spatial reference.

Finally, cast the point into [IGeometry5 and call ProjectEx](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ProjectEx_Method/002m000001rp000000/), passing the target spatial reference and the geotransformation.  IPoint.X and IPoint.Y should then represent longitude and latitude of the point where the user clicked.

Comment: British National Grid does require datum transformation - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid#Datum_shift_between_OSGB_36_and_WGS_84

Answer (score 3):

If you use the identify tool to click anywhere on the map, you can change the type of units displayed in the location bar.  There is a (very tiny!) button at the end of the location bar that when clicked will open a menu displaying a list of unit types to display.  Simply select Decimal Degrees or D/M/S to get your lat/long.

edit: Here's a screenshot:
[image: Set Identify Units]

Another simple option is to switch your display units to Decimal Degrees (Data Frame Properties, General tab - set Display: to Decimal degrees).  Then you can see the units in DD displayed at the bottom/right as you move the mouse cursor.