# Get coordinates from current view using arcobjects

Tags: arcobjects, coordinates, bookmarks

I'm wondering if there's a way to get the longitude/latitude coordinates from the center of a data frame? The problem I'm faced with is this: I want to set a bookmark and have ArcMap tell me the coordinates of the center of that bookmark. (Without using a mouse. This all needs to be automated.)
This is akin to hovering one's mouse over the center of a map and reciting the long./lat. numbers that are shown at the bottom of the ArcMap window.

I'm pretty "green" when it comes to VBA programming in ArcMap 10.0. At first I thought I could utilize the "Info" tool, but now I'm guessing that I need to get the use the IEnvelope interface to calculate the center of the map, then grab the coordinates from that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the IActiveView.Extent property.  You can cast an IMap to an IActiveView and vice versa.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001200000199000000

The Extent property will return an IEnvelope that has an X and Y Max and Min that you can use to calculate the center if you would like.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000169000000

To get the IActiveView instance you can use the IApplication.Document property and cast the Document to an IMxDocument.  You can then get an IActiveView using IMxDocument.ActiveView property.  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//004900000054000000

Some code-

```
Dim mxDocument As ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument = CType(application.Document, ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI.IMxDocument) ' Explicit Cast
Dim activeView As ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IActiveView = mxDocument.ActiveView
Dim currentExtent As IEnvelope = activeView.Extent
//TODO::  Get Max/Min X and Y from currentExtent and calculate the center point.
```

Here is a gis.stackexchange post that describes taking a map x,y and converting it to a lat, long.
[Extracting lat/long from screen when using British National Grid projection in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/extract-lat-long-from-screen-when-using-british-national-grid-projection)

In particular, follow these steps-

> I'm not that familiar the the British National Grid, but it appears
>   that a datum transformation is required when projecting to WGS84.
>
> So, use ISpatialReferenceFactory.CreateGeoTransformation to create the
>   appropriate datum transformation, and
>   ISpatialReferenceFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem to create
>   the target (WGS84) spatial reference.
>
> Finally, cast the point into IGeometry5 and call ProjectEx, passing
>   the target spatial reference and the geotransformation. IPoint.X and
>   IPoint.Y should then represent longitude and latitude of the point
>   where the user clicked.

Comment: Thanks, Darlene. I think what you're describing can be found here: http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/23078

That code will return the center position of the map document, but the next step should be to find whichever longitude and latitude coordinates correspond to that point *in the map's contents*. So this gets me halfway there!

Comment: Would it be practical to try this?
1) Get the center of the display (using the code above).
2) Draw a point at those x/y coordinates.
3) Get the lat/long of the point.
4) Delete the point.
5) Re-project the map using the derived lat/long.

Comment: This stack exchange post describes how to convert a map point to a lat/long.  It is similar to what you proposed.  I don't think you need to draw and delete the point; I would expect you to be able to work with the point in memory.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7114/extract-lat-long-from-screen-when-using-british-national-grid-projection

Comment: That uses a mouse click event, and I mentioned in my first post that we're trying to automate this process, not use a mouse.

Comment: Right, you can ignore the part that talks about a mouse click event.  You will get your IPoint from calculating the center point of your IEnvelope.  Then you can use your IPoint as described in the post I linked to that states to use IGeometry5.ProjectEx(targetSpatialRef, geoTransformation).

Comment: Currently looking at a different approach to this. I found this post which indicates that my original inquiry is probably not possible: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/53050-Determine-spatial-reference-from-X-Y-values?highlight=point+coordinates

My new question has been posted here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68843/finding-points-in-extent-using-vba