# Finding points in extent using VBA

Tags: arcobjects, vba

Is there a way to select a point from my map's current extent? I want to use ArcObjects to tell me if there is at least one point visible in my extent. I'd like to do this entirely in VBA, and without *selecting* any features or using any mouse-click events. (Selection can be done programmatically, just not manually.)

An demonstration would show that I have a point-type shapefile active and positioned at the top of my Table of Contents. I run my code which then displays a message box showing the longitude and latitude of the first point that is found within the current extent. Any point can be found and it's coordinates returned, just as long as that point is within the given extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by getting the envelope from the current extent and creating a query filter from the envelope. See the posts at this [link](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=69538).